# Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I started learning gitlab-ci using a course on udemy. Below code is absolutely similar to the master's code but his code run correctly but my code release error.
what is wrong with below code:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  
build the car:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir build
    - touch car.txt
    - echo "chassis" >> car.txt
    - echo "engine" >> car.txt
    - echo "wheels" >> car.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/

test the car:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ls    
    - test -f build/car.txt
    - cd build
    - ls
    - cat car.txt
    - grep "chassis" car.txt
    - grep "engine" car.txt
    - grep "wheels" car.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `build` directory but your `car.txt` is at the root folder, therefore not part of the artifact and not existing in the test stage.

Your structure now:

```
.
├── /build
├── car.txt
```

How it should be

```
.
├── /build
│   └── car.txt
```

You should refactor all `car.txt` related commands to `build/car.txt`.

If you are doing an udemy course, you might wanna have a look at variables so that you can assign the filepath to a variable and don't run into problems if you need to relate to the same path in different commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just some more anecdotal evidence:

In my case I did do the following installation of a global .NET tool twice:

```yaml
- dotnet tool install --global cs-script.cli
- dotnet tool update --global cs-script.cli
```

I did it once in the [`before_script` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) (that runs before every stage) and also accidentally in my `publish` stage.

So I guess that after doing the cleanup for the `before_script` stage by removing the tool, the cleanup for the explicit installation of the tool in the `publish` stage failed (because the files were already removed by the `before_script` cleanup).

**My solution** was to remove the second, redundant installation of the .NET tool in the `publish` stage.